# How is matter different from space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, speed-of-light, vacuum, aether

Scientists used to think that light requires a medium to travel, and it is aether. Then they conclude that there's no aether.

Later quantum physics found that space is not empty, it's a thing.

(i.e. the lowest state of quantum fields with particles popping in and out of it - [Quantum vacuum state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_vacuum_state)).

Then, regarding the travelling of light in it, how is space different from matter?

And how does the fact that space is not empty affect the travelling of light in it?

Comment: *"Later quantum physics found that space is not empty, it's a thing."* [citation needed]

Comment: @ACuriousMind I edited it

Comment: Matter has mass. Light isn't matter either, nor is it space.

Comment: @DKNguyen Light is matter too. It's the matter that takes care of the em interaction. It doesn't have mass though. Only energy.

Answer (score -5):

To address your question directly, let me state what the Aether is supposed to mean. It is supposed to be a space with some unseen matter (supposed to be absolutely at rest wrt to this space, except for the motions it exhibits when an electromagnetic wave has to be supported) in it through which electromagnetic radiation travels. With the consequence that if we are at rest wrt this unseen matter we measure different propagation speeds of the em radiation. In the modern conception of a vacuum, empty space contains virtual particles (to put it simply). But these particles don't constitute the matter that is supposed to be there in Aether. Electromagnetic fields are not a distortion of these virtual particles (that travels through this collection of virtual particles). This is not to say that virtual particles don't influence em waves. If we move fast wrt to the stars, we will see the same vacuum with virtual particles in it. These virtual particles are not some kind of matter that is at rest in an absolute way.

Einstein said that a developing spacetime cannot exist without matter inside it (see for example [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2014-1) article). I don't see though why truly empty space cannot exist on its own. Even though matter has to be in it (according to Einstein), the space surrounding the matter exists independently of this matter though matter somehow tells it how to evolve.
Even in the picture given by quantum field theory, which states that empty space is not truly empty, but instead full of vacuum fluctuations, this is so. Empty space is empty space. Space not being empty doesn't imply that it is a thing like the real particles that it can contain (as you state in your question). Space not being empty (but filled with the vacuum configuration of the quantum fields of all elementary particles) doesn't imply that there are real particles in it though. The lowest quantum field configuration of all elementary particles corresponds to virtual particles. So not to real particles.
This means that anywhere inside this vacuum state there is a probability that a real particle is created when you add energy to the vacuum. But how do you add this energy if there are no real particles?
It can be done by molding empty spacetime in such a way that it becomes a spacetime that has high intrinsic curvature. This is "done" around a black hole. Space surrounding a black hole spits out real particles (Hawking radiation), thereby changing the shape of the spacetime surrounding the hole, which eventually can lead to the evaporation of the hole (though in practice there is more mass gained as radiated away).
But how do you twist spacetime into a state with high intrinsic curvature without the help of a black hole? That is, without real particles? There must exist real particles in the first place to twist spacetime. It turns out though that spacetime can have high intrinsic curvature without matter being inside it (the stress energy-momentum can be zero everywhere, while spacetime has non-zero curvature). How does his match with Einstein's idea that spacetime cannot exist without matter in it? Einstein was talking about an evolving spacetime. But curved spacetime configurations exist that are momentarily empty. They will not stay empty forever. Matter will emerge in such a spacetime.
I can't see other ways to add energy to empty spacetime, as in an empty spacetime no real particles are present. Of course, you can add energy, say in the form of real photons, by just shooting a photon in empty space. But then real particles have to be already there. As is the case in the present universe.
How does a non-empty vacuum (not a vacuum with real particles) affect real particles traveling through it? This non-empty vacuum has several effects on these real particles. One of them is the [Zitterbewegung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zitterbewegung) of elementary particles like quarks and leptons. Due to the non-empty vacuum their motion somewhat disturbed ("zittern", a german verb, means to shiver, more or less). This has observable consequences. The Lamb-shift is caused by this non-empty vacuum too. Photons, if they have a high enough energy, can create pairs of particles-antiparticles.
But what is the Nature of space? Is it particle-like? If so, then the particles involved are not the same as elementary particles. If not, then what is space? It's somewhat like the water surrounding particles that are suspended in it, though the water is made out of molecules. I think it's very hard to say out of what kind of molecules space is made. Loop quantum gravity in some sense gives meaning to these molecules, but these molecules are made of space themselves, so...
We'll never know, I guess. Likewise, we'll never know the true Nature of matter. But what we do know is that they are different. I guess...

There are some obvious differences. Matter moves through spacetime while spacetime movement is a movement of spacetime itself. Spacetime is flexible, while elementary particles are not. Unless you envision them as higher-dimensional structures, as in string theory. Or whatever different contorted structure. Maybe particles are rigid four-dimensional structures that are tightly folded in five-dimensional space to form seemingly three-dimensional structures that fit in our space. Obviously, space has to be four-dimensional too for these particles to fit in it. But if space is folded just as tight as the particles, you won't notice that space is four-dimensional. In fact, the particles follow the curved form of the space in this peculiar case. What more differences? Matter particles have a charge and mass. Space has not. Matter particles can form complex structures. Space cannot, though space does have a structure that conforms to Einstein's field equations.
What are the similarities between space and matter? There are none, though if you consider particles to be made of space, they're obviously the same, basically.   Maybe atoms of spacetime exist (just like macroscopic matter is built from atoms), as proposed by Loop Quantum Gravity, though these cannot be viewed as small (Planck sized) four-dimensional cubes which, when stapled together, form the whole of spacetime. Loop Quantum Gravity (as the name suggests) is a quantum gravity candidate that quantizes spacetime itself instead of fields on a smooth spacetime. The atoms of space in this theory are quantum objects. For example, you can't measure the volume and its surface with infinite precision which is a form of the uncertainty relation as it exists in ordinary quantum mechanics. Only for very small spacetime scales, this uncertainty becomes important.

Though matter and space(time) are different, they can't exist without each other. Particles need evolving space to exist in and evolving space needs particles to exist. Maybe both are fundamentally equal. Maybe one day a theory is found that treats particles as a contortion of (a higher dimensional) space itself, being submerged somehow in the large-scale structure of space, which is, on the smallest scale, maybe a higher dimensional structure to make these space contortions fit. If matter turns out to be space **all* is just an evolving space(time).

I forgot one thing. You ask:

> Then, regarding the traveling of light in it, how is space different from matter?

Very different. Light only travels through space, and not through matter (it can travel through glass but in the end, it travels only in the space between matter particles making up the glass). Just like matter can travel only through space. Both light and matter are represented by fields permeating space (and time). Space is not the same as matter, as I tried to show. Space is not a thing because later quantum physics found that it is not empty. Light doesn't travel in a matter medium.

To put it in one phrase: the new aether is Lorentz-invariant spacetime and particles (quarks, leptons, and the three basic forces eventually complemented with Higgs particles, and maybe to be replaced by more fundamental particles) are excitations of the corresponding quantum fields, while gravity is concerned with stress-energy contorted spacetime.

Comment: @Yuht.D Finally, a reaction. What is written between the parentheses shows a wrong understanding of spacetime. Space is simple that what particles move in. Just as you walk outside through the space enclosed in your house. What is there more to it? That you can't understand what I write is something different.

Comment: @Yuht.D I gave a very short aanwer at the end of my space-contorted writings...I'm not sure though I understand the aether you have in mind. Does it contain matter? Like the vacuum contains virtual matter? I think you confuse the meaning of real and virtual.. **Is** the Aether you have in mind this vacuum? Obviously, yes. But why do you think that this introduces a new Aether? This new Aether you propose  (which really exists) is Lorentz invariant, so it is not an Aether in the sense that it is stationary somehow. Can you envision space to be a stationary thing?

Comment: @Yuht:D Aether was supposed to be something to be at rest absolutely. All things were supposed to be moving wrt to this Aether. maybe the "thing" that comes the closest to this "thing" is the frame in which the CMBR shows no red (or blue) shift, but this is just an arbitrary frame too. All CMBR could just as well have existed in another frame that moves wrt to it.